# How to implement different ranking algorithms in tf-ranking framework?

Tags: tensorflow, ranking, google-ranking

What is the algorithm behind tf-ranking? and can we use Lambdamart algorithm in tf-ranking .Can anyone suggest some good sources to learn these

Answer (score 0):

TF Ranking provides a framework for you to implement your own algorithm. It helps you set up the components around the core of your model (input_fn, metrics and loss functions, etc.). But the scoring logic (aka scoring function) should be provided by the user.

You probably have already seen these, but just in case:

[TF-Ranking: Scalable TensorFlow Library for Learning-to-Rank](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.00073)

and

[Learning Groupwise Multivariate Scoring Functions Using Deep Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.04415)